# How to get nginx cookie value by cookie name

Tags: nginx, cookies

I am trying to get cookie value by name in nginx.

My code is:

```
if ($request_uri ~* /id/(.*)\?x){
  set $id $1;
  set $my_cookiename id-$id;
}


if ($http_cookie ~* $my_cookiename"=([a-z0-9]+)(?:;|$)") {
    set $my_cookievalue $1;
}

location /id {
        default_type 'text/plain';
        echo $my_cookievalue;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Nginx already supports [`$cookie_`](http://nginx.org/r/$cookie_)-style syntax for accessing individual cookies.

However, a better way to do what you're trying to do would be through a [`map`](http://nginx.org/r/map) or two.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing a similar task. At this moment I've written such a map:

```
map $cookie_name $backend {
        default alb;
        ~(.*) $1;
}
```

Maybe this will help you a little.